# Why does remove_if( ..., lambda ) expression require the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, lambda, operator-overloading

I have this code (simplified) :

```
std::vector<Session> sessions;
// ...
std::remove_if( sessions.begin(), sessions.end(), 
   [] (const Session& s) {
      return false;
   }
);
```

When I compile it (in Visual Studio 2013 Update 1) I get the following error:

```
algorithm(1759): error C2280: 'Session &Session::operator =(const Session &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
   Session.h(78) : see declaration of 'Session::operator ='
```

Indeed, I have deleted `operator=` in the `Session` class like this:

```
Session& operator= (const Session& that) = delete;
```

My **question** is: why does that `remove_if` using a lambda expression require the assignment operator? Where is one `Session` object assigned to another?

**Update:** As explained by @nosid and @Praetorian `remove_if` requires either move or copy constructor & assignment operator. According to the C++11 standard the move constructor/assignment operator should have been auto-generated by the compiler. Unfortunately [Visual Studio 2013 does not do that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). Since the class is not copyable `remove_if` cannot resort to copying, either, so the compiler displays the error. I fixed it by manually implementing a move constructor and a move assignment operator.

Comment: It's not the _lambda expression_ that requires `operator=`. It's the algorithm `std::remove_if`, because it moves elements (instead of removing them).

Comment: @nosid: That sounds good. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Rewrote question a touch: while it does not match your original question exactly (the problem wasn't where you thought it was, after all), it should be easier to search for for people who have the same problem.

Comment: Someone appears to have not read the docs for `remove_if`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is not caused by the lambda expression. The lambda expression is fine, as can be seen if you replace `remove_if` with `all_of`:

```
// OK
std::all_of(_sessions.begin(), _sessions.end(), 
    [](const Session& session) { return false; });
```

The error is caused by the algorithm `std::remove_if`. Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range. For that reason, a copy or move assignment is required.

You will see the same error message for other algorithm that require copy or move assignment operations, even if they are used without a lambda expression. Here is an example:

```
// ERROR: Session& operator=(const Session&) is private
std::move(std::next(_sessions.begin()), _sessions.end(), _sessions.begin());
```

Answer (score 7):

[`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)  requires that the objects obtained by dereferencing the iterator be MoveAssignable (§25.3.8/1). But because you've explicitly `delete`d the copy assignment operator, the move assignment operator is also implicitly `delete`d.

Assuming `Session` can support move semantics, you can get `remove_if` to work by defining a move assignment operator. For instance, simply adding a `default`ed move assignment operator is enough to fix the immediate problem (note that you may not be able to depend on the compiler generated version and might have to define one yourself).

```
Session& operator=(Session&&) = default;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/684bccf034180e84)

---

VS2013 does not support defaulted move constructor/assignment operator, so in your case you'll be forced to implement one.

Comment: I think the requirement is a little fuzzier than that, I think it requires the object be nothrow-move-assignable or is copy-assignable.  That's how most of the containers work anyway, I assume `remove_if` does as well.

Comment: @MooingDuck You'd think so, but this is all it says - *Requires: The type of `*first` shall satisfy the MoveAssignable requirements*.

Comment: Ah, it defines `MoveAssignable` as `t = rv`, which means throwing moves are allowed, and it can use copy assign as a fallback.  Now I know.

Answer (score 2):

- In `std::remove_if` there're some assignments/moves happening between the elements of the range you pass as input.
- It seems though, that the assignment operator of `Session` class is deleted (i.e., `Session` objects have been made un-assignable by the implementer of class `Session`).
- Therefore, the compiler rightfully complains that it can't assign objects of type `Session`.

---

Below is a possible implementation of `remove_if`:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIt remove_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    first = std::find_if(first, last, p);
    if (first != last)
        for(ForwardIt i = first; ++i != last; )
            if (!p(*i))
                *first++ = std::move(*i); // COMPILER SAYS I CAN'T DO THIS!!!
    return first;
}
```

Comment: There are no _swaps_ happening in `std::remove_if`.

Comment: @nosid I don't mean `std::swap` I mean shifts like you do :P